# How To Fix Errors in ContextWrapper.java That Comes After Updating

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm still a beginner on Android Studio, and when I update some features bunch of errors come from ContextWrapper.java class. I was trying to find the solution but I didn't get one. Can someone help me to fix this, its really confusing me.

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlckV.png)

Comment: You don't need to worry about those errors, However, if you want you can sync Gradle, your build will run fine.

Comment: But, even if it doesn't affect the app I'm still curious about the cause of the error xd